# How do you configure a naked domain without access to DNS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, subdomain, cname-record

I registered a domain with registro.br. It's a Brazilian domain, and they do things differently.

Usually, I would register a domain and the registrar would provide me with a panel to configure options for my domain. Registro.br doesn't do this. You simply point your domain to the DNS details from your host.

That's fine. Only now I'm trying to host my own site on Amazon EC2. I have no host that can give me access to CNAME records and such. I have an instance and an elastic IP.

How can I create sub-domains and CNAME records in this case?

My intention is to have `mysubdomain.mydomain.com.br` point to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/site1` and `mysubdomain2.mydomain.com.br` point to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/site2`

Comment: Its unclear, but are you trying to ask how to setup a DNS server?  What do you mean 'domain without DNS' thats pretty much a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm reading you right then you need to purchase a DNS service from someone. Point the NS records at registro.br to the name servers for your DNS service then use that to set up the A and CNAME records that point to your EC2 instance.

Comment: It seems that you need to run your own DNS servers, and you need static IPs for that.  If "elastic IP" means "non-static IP", then you can't do that for yourself, and as Iain says, you'll need to rent it off someone.

Comment: Elastic IPs are static.

Comment: It took a few minutes, but lain is right. A few years back, most registers usually just setup NS records - you have to have a different provider to host DNS. Looks like in this case, this is what the poster needs to do.

Comment: Thanks, Iain; it wasn't a term I'd come across before.  Then the OP can run his own DNS server if he wants to, but as you said, he must either run it or rent it since the registrar isn't providing it.

Comment: @MadHatter: EC2 Elastic IP Address: Internet routable IP address allocated to an AWS EC2 account. Unlike a standard EC2 Public IP Address, Elastic IP Addresses are allocated to accounts and can be remapped to other instances when desired.